# .NET Combobox SelectedValue After Databinding Complete

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

I am using a class to add a set of controls to a form. One is a combobox. I bind a datasource using a datatable.

However, if I then try to SelectValue programmatically I find that the databinding is not complete and it throws an error. Does anyone know if there is way to bind after the databinding?

```
Dim cb As New ComboBox
With cb
    .DataSource = _dtDropDown
    .ValueMember = "ID"
    .DisplayMember = "Descr"
End With

cb.SelectedIndex = _selectedID
```

Comment: I actually got it to work by adding the SelectedIndex action to a method handling BindingContextChanged on the control, but I'm not sure that's ideal.

Comment: Do not set the ValueMember and DisplayMember after the DataSource.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. So, where should that be set?

Comment: Just move the .DataSource line after the other two.

Comment: Hi @Blam, This is for WinForm.